# Task ToObservable Error Handling

Tags: refactoring, system.reactive, dotnet-httpclient, reactiveui

I have the following method which is responsible for calling my service class and passing the results off to another method for saving them in my db:

```
public IObservable<bool> SyncSessions()
{
    var subject = new ReplaySubject<bool>();

    try
    {
        var query = new ByFilterQuery { SearchPeriodStartTime = DateTime.Now };
        var sessions = _sessionService.GetSessions(query).Result;
        var saved = SaveSessions(sessions);
        subject.OnNext(saved);
        subject.OnCompleted();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        subject.OnError(ex);
    }

    return subject;
 }
```

_sessionService.GetSessions will throw a HttpRequestException if the server returns a 500 or something similar. I have a unit test which mocks this behaviour and want to test my method handles the error gracefully.

Is there any better ways of propagating the error in the Rx fashion? I tried doing:

```
_sessionService.GetSessions(query).ToObservable().Select(SaveSessions);
```

But this threw my error instead of it being passed to the error handling action in the calling method. I also plan to merge this method with several others and handle the errors in a combined manor.

EDIT: Here is how I was subscribing to the observable

```
Exception error = null;
_sessionManager
    .SyncSessions()
    .Subscribe(null, e => error = e);

Assert.That(error, Is.Not.Null.After(500));
```

I'm passing null into the first parameter as I don't really care about that in the context of this test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for the original code you posted, I recommend using an [AsyncSubject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229363%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) instead of a `ReplaySubject`.  Think of it as being optimized for the single-result case.

Now on to your question...

Whenever an observable source generates an exception, that exception is propagated through the `OnError` handler.  If, when you subscribe to the observable, you do not supply an `OnError` handler, then the exception will be thrown.

The small code you posted:

```
_sessionService.GetSessions(query).ToObservable().Select(SaveSessions);
```

is not enough.  Without also posting the code that shows how you subscribe to the observable I can only guess that you did not supply an `OnError` handler.

**Edit based on OP's test code**

Is your mock service returning a `Task` that throws an exception, or is the mock service just throwing the exception?  Unless you are using async/await, a function that is supposed to return a `Task`, but throws an exception while creating that `Task` will raise the exception immediately instead of returning a failed `Task`.  ToObservable never even gets called because GetSessions throws.  If you change your mock service to return a failed `Task` then your test will probably work correctly.

If you want to catch immediate exceptions as well as failed tasks, then you can use `Defer` to defer execution of your method until an observer subscribes.  It will also collect any immediately thrown exceptions in addition to failed tasks:

```
return Observable
    .Defer(() => _sessionService.GetSessions(query))
    .Select(SaveSessions);
```

Comment: Test was throwing an error. GetSessions() has a call to response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); so it may throw an error